# What is the best way to share data throughout all activites?

Tags: java, android, http, location

So all of my activities will need the current location of the device, as well as a set of data retrieved through a Http request. I was wondering what is the best way to find this information once, and share it across all my activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass (or persist) data between application's activities, you can either use:

1. `SharedPreferences`:

> Shared Preferences allows activities and applications to keep preferences, in the form of key-value pairs similar to a Map that will persist even when the user closes the application.
>
> Android stores Shared Preferences settings as XML file in shared_prefs folder under DATA/data/{application package} directory. The DATA folder can be obtained by calling Environment.getDataDirectory().

[Link to SharedPreferences example tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial).

2. `Intent.putExtra(...)`

> Whenever you need data from an activity to be in another activity, you can pass data between then while starting the activities. Intents in android offer this convenient way to pass data between activities using Extras.

[Link to Intent pass data through extras tutorial](https://zocada.com/using-intents-extras-pass-data-activities-android-beginners-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences to save data for Android. And get preferences when you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Find your scenario:

1. If you are going to use a very small amount of data like name, phone
   no, or some value, which you want to store even if the app is closed, then use **shared preference.**
2. If you are going to use a list of object (`List<Object>`) and is a
   large amount of data, which you want to store even if the app is closed, then use `ROOM/SQLite` for it.
3. If you are going to use a list of object(`List<Object>`) and is a
   small amount of data, which you want to store only when the app is
   active, then use the **static** object.

I Think, you should use shared preference for location and static variable which is being retrieved from the network.

If you want to use the current location of the device, use `fusedLocationProviderClient` once you get it, store it in shared preference. Whenever you the location is provided by `fusedLocationProviderClient` update the **shared preference** data.

If the data retrieved from the network is an object and changes every time you open the app and is a small amount of data, then use the **static** variable, or else use `ROOM/SQLite`